# Accessing primary paramater array in response of a ksoap2 on android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am using `ksoap2` webservice from my android application. I get the following Response from the server:

```
validateUserResponse{return=anyType{authenticated=true; contactNumber=9856456589; 
***currentAssignedVillagesName=Vavol; currentAssignedVillagesName=Chotila; 
currentVillageCode=6; currentVillageCode=18;*** dob=697228200000; firstTimeLogin=false; 
id=87; languageCode=EN; password=3r68IuRgxV 7lLT6FylQ5bONeimCbehq; 
serverDate=1367224983096; userContactId=163; userRole=Asha; username=umehta; fName=Umang; 
lName=Mehta; }; }
```

As in the response there is a variable **currentAssignedVillagesName** which is an `array` of `String` and **currentVillageCode** `array` of `int`.

I am unable to access these variables with `getProperty()` method. Any solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just do two things as follows:

Add a statement as:

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

before the call as:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

and add statement as:

```
String xml = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
```

after the call statement, and you will get the response in XML in the form of XML data as tags and data.

Just parse the data using any parsing method.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: Duplicate field currentAssignedVillagesName

Comment: I did the same as you instructed, got a XML String, parsed that string and got the above error

Comment: The place where I tried to convert the XML string into JAVA BEAN.

Comment: So its not the issue in ksoap2 response. The issue is in your conversion. You just try to use the parsing as SAX and then use the data. The ans is for getting proper response. If it is helpful vote and accept. An one more thing as if you are not able to do so just let me know.